# NoSuchMethodError in Hamcrest with Android unit test

Tags: android, junit4

I am trying to use an ExpectedException @Rule in my Android JUnit4 unit test, but the test is failing with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch`.

Other questions suggest that I have an old version of Hamcrest in one of my other libraries, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I've excluded Hamcrest from all the other libraries, and am explicitly including Hamcrest 1.3.

```
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
testCompile ('junit:junit:4.12') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
testCompile ('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
testCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
}
testCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
}
```

And here's the dependency graph.

```
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- junit:junit:4.12
+--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19
|    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
+--- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19
|    \--- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:1.6.2
|         +--- org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.2
|         |    +--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.6.2
|         |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.19.0-GA
|         \--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.6.2
\--- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2
     +--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:1.6.2
          +--- junit:junit:4.4 -> 4.12
          +--- org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.2 (*)
          \--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.6.2
```

If I don't include Hamcrest as an explicit dependency then I get a `ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher`, so nothing else is including it.

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 with Gradle plugin 1.2.3.

Comment: It really seems a library mismatch. Check the classpath. The error is thrown from both Gradle test plugin and Idea launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the caches in Android Studio (File->Invalidate Caches/Restart) fixed my problem. Excluding Hamcrest from JUnit and Mockito wasn't needed.